# $\lim _{z\rightarrow -i}\dfrac{1}{z-i}=\dfrac{i}{2}$ Why this answer?

Tags: limits, image-processing

$i$ is imaginary number.
I think this quiestion.
$$\lim _{z\rightarrow -i}\dfrac{1}{z-i}=\dfrac{i}{2}$$
I think this answer is $-\dfrac{1}{2i}$.

I don't know why this answer is $\dfrac{i}{2}$.
please tell me.

Comment: They're equal! Note $i^2=-1$ implies $i^{-1}=-i$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
-\frac{1}{2i} = -\frac{i}{(2i)i} = -\frac{i}{-2} = \frac{i}{2}
$$

Comment: Oh! I can understand this question. Thank you very much.